# In the CentOS7, AttributeError: module 'socketio' has no attribute 'Server'

Tags: python, socket.io, centos7

I have a Django project, I use git push to the remote repo.

I have installed the `python-socketio` in my remote repo (remote server is CentOS7.2), when I execute:

```
(venv_dist) xxx$ python3 manage.py runserver
```

I get bellow error:

> AttributeError: module 'socketio' has no attribute 'Server'

But, if in my local repo, I installed `python-socketio` in my local repo `venv`, I can execute python3 `manage.py runserver` success.

Why in the remote I can not execute success?

The related code is:

```
import os

from django.http import HttpResponse
import socketio

basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sio = socketio.Server(async_mode=async_mode)
thread = None
```

---

**EDIT-1**

```
# pip3 show python-socketio
Name: python-socketio
Version: 1.9.0
Summary: Socket.IO server
Home-page: http://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/
Author: Miguel Grinberg
Author-email: miguelgrinberg50@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/lll/repo/myProject/venv_dist/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: python-engineio, six
Required-by:
```

---

Comment: It could be that socketio is already installed as a system library. If you do `socketio.__path__` where does it say it is installed? Also, what does `socketio.__version__` return?

Comment: What is the output of `pip3 show python-socketio` on the remote server?

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have [`socketio`](https://pypi.org/project/socketio/) installed as well as [`python-socketio`](https://pypi.org/project/python-socketio/)`?

These are different projects. They *both* install a package called `socketio`.

`python-socketio` is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things which you can do

- Check site-packages folder where all library files resides - I am guessing you will have .egg files for socket and other libraries
- Uninstall all the dependent libraries and re-install.
- Make sure install once. If already installed you should always use upgrade command